# Python 3.4 listening to selected server and port

Tags: python, sockets

This code can create socket, connect to selected server and port, and print reply. I have a question, how can I listening to the port longer than one moment? E.g. I want listen to selected port for 20 seconds and print all packets which will come at this time. Is it possible with this code?

```
import socket
import sys

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

except socket.error as msg:
    print("Failed to create socket. Error code: " + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1])
    sys.exit();

print('Socket Created')

host = #server
port = #port
try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:
    print('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

print('Ip address of ' + host + ' is ' + remote_ip)

s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print('Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip)

reply = s.recv(4096)

print(reply)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of looping?

Comment: Loops can't help with this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the timeout for the socket should fit your requirement if I understand correctly that you just need to wait one time for 20 seconds.

```
s.settimeout(20)
reply = s.recv(4096)
```

[Python Socket settimeout()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)

However you are not guaranteed to get all the data packets delivered at once. So as was mentioned in a comment, you should be looping. The way to do this would be to place the socket in nonblocking mode.

Outside of your loop, you need a `buffer_variable` that would hold the total results from the recv().

Prior to entering your loop, you would start a timer. Upon entering you loop you would begin calling `recv()` on the socket while saving the result in a `local_variable`. Each time you get something new in `local_variable` you append it to `buffer_variable`.

When the timer expires, you would then `break` the loop, and process your data from `buffer_variable` accordingly.